# Printing Superscript / Subscript in RPGLE on iSeries (AS/400)

Tags: ibm-midrange, subscript, rpgle, superscript

How to print subscript / superscript through RPGLE into spool file. This gets converted to pdf at the end.

How to print "1st" as 1 (superscript) using RPGLE.
The printer field type is character length 15.

External printer file. 
Printer device type  . . . . . . . . . :   *AFPDS

coded  as @Symbo = '1'  x'09  'st' x'03
it prints "1 st ", with special characters in place of hex x'09 & x'03 but not as 1 (superscript).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you view or print the formatted printer file before it gets converted to pdf to see how the viewer or printer renders it?  What program is doing the pdf conversion (CPYSPLF, SPLMATIC/SPLCONVERT, etc)?

Comment: This may not be easily doable depending on your context. What are you doing that requires a superscript? Are you creating a letter? or some other type of document? Maybe you would be better off to just create it as a Word Document which has subscript/superscript functionality. *AFPDS will let you set fonts, and position the type on the page, but creating a superscript would have to be a manual process requiring you to know the exact position of the `1` so you could locate the smaller font.

Comment: @Mike, yes I can view the spool file before it get converted. I am using SPLMATIC/SPLCONVERT to convert to pdf.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy, I need this capability to print electrical symbols in documents. There are thousands of documents using these symbols. I just posted example of 1st.

Comment: When you look at the spool file before conversion, are the superscript characters printed as superscript?